# Boot problem with custom preseed in 18.04: /dev/ram does not exist

Tags: grub2, system-installation, 18.04, preseed

I'm trying to adapt our preseed installation image from 16.04 to 18.04

These are the lines from the grub `txt.cfg`:

```
kernel /casper/vmlinuz
append  preseed/file=/cdrom/preseed/sc-server.seed debian-installer/locale=en_US \
        keyboard-configuration/layoutcode=de \
        initrd=/casper/initrd ramdisk_size=16384 root=/dev/ram rw  --
```

<sub>actually a single line, placed in multiple lines for readability</sub>

This works fine on 16.04, but on 18.04 it results in the following:

> ALERT! /dev/ram does not exist. Dropping to a shell!

I can't find any device in `/dev` that has a reasonable name for a ramdrive. Has the device been renamed? Do I have to load an extra module? I can't find any information about that bin [in the documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/amd64/apb.html) or via popular search engines. Just omitting the parameter doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured it out.

I was missing the parameter `boot=casper` in the `append` line. With the parameter the iso boots.

---

An additional note for someone who runs into the same problem while trying to get a preseed installation working: The preseed files don't work with the new installer. Currently Ubuntu provides an additional installation image with the old installer, [currently available here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04/release/). With this image (server without "live" in the filename) the problem above doesn't occur and the preseed files work.